# Wrap HTML Element With Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I  have following Code in HTML

```
<div class="newloop_11"></div>
<div class="newloop_12"></div>
<div class="newloop_13"></div>
<div class="newloop_14"></div>
<div class="newloop_15"></div>
<div class="newloop_16"></div>

And When i call a ajax request on any event 

i got following HTML 

<div class="replacewith_11 textme loop" id="test_1">
//lotsof content

</div>
<div class="replacewith_12 textme loop" id="test_2">
//lotsof content

</div>
<div class="replacewith_13 textme loop" id="test_3">
//lotsof content

</div>
```

Now I want to wrap ajax html with previous HTML

if their value is matched

Expectd out like this

```
<div class="replacewith_11 textme loop" id="test_1">
//lotsof content

</div>
<div class="replacewith_12 textme loop" id="test_2">
//lotsof content

</div>
<div class="replacewith_13 textme loop" id="test_3">
//lotsof content

</div>
<div class="newloop_14"></div>
<div class="newloop_15"></div>
<div class="newloop_16"></div>
```

How to do this in Jquery.

I tried InnerHTML, append, html method, but i have no idea how to do this

Any Help will be apprecaited

Thanks

Comment: This could be useful: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Comment: Also, post the code you've tried and didn't work.

Comment: Try to use test() function to get right divs. Then when the number matches with the ajax respond number use before() to put its html before the matching newloop div. Then remove the newloop div with matching number.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use jquery [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) inside success of your ajax call:

```
$(".newloop_13").after("<div>your ajax result</div>");
```

See an example here: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xe6c6n5a/11/)